# attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteQuery

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

Okay, I'm lost and saying 'uncle.'  I'm getting the 'attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteQuery' error message - see log below.  As you can see the error occurs in the method pasted below.  It was working fine.  Interestingly enough, I just added a cursor.close to a complete other method where it was missing one because I was getting a 'SQLite Android Database Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed' message.

But I'm not sure why this method would start throwing an error?  The cursor.close has always been in the same location, never caused an error before, and appears correct. Completely lost.

I looked at these posts below, but I seem to be doing things correctly as far as I can tell. Thanks for the help!

[Android - attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteQuery using loaderManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17458251/android-attempt-to-re-open-an-already-closed-object-sqlitequery-using-loaderm)

[attempt to reopen an already-closed object: sqlitequery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18906571/attempt-to-reopen-an-already-closed-object-sqlitequery)

```
public List<dbData> queryToList(String myTable, String[] myColumns, String whereClause,
                                String[] whereArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orberBy) {
    System.out.println("start queryToList");
    List<dbData> dbDatas = new ArrayList<>();

    Cursor cursor = database.query(myTable, myColumns,
            whereClause, whereArgs, groupBy, having, orberBy);
    System.out.println("cursor count = " + cursor.getCount());
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        dbData dbData = cursorToDB_Row(cursor, myTable);
        dbData.setIntTemp1(0);
        dbDatas.add(dbData);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    // make sure to close the cursor
    cursor.close();
    return dbDatas;

}
```

Log:

```
03-21 21:51:44.695    9457-9457/com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders I/System.out﹕ start changeReminder
03-21 21:51:44.695    9457-9457/com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders I/System.out﹕ start Reminder
03-21 21:51:44.695    9457-9457/com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders I/System.out﹕ savePreference for reminder
03-21 21:51:44.695    9457-9457/com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders I/System.out﹕ start determineReminder
03-21 21:51:44.695    9457-9457/com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders I/System.out﹕ start relationshipSpace
03-21 21:51:44.695    9457-9457/com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders I/System.out﹕ start queryToList
03-21 21:51:44.705    9457-9457/com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders I/System.out﹕ cursor count = 110
03-21 21:51:44.705    9457-9457/com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders, PID: 9457
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteQuery: SELECT * FROM reminders
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:58)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:178)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.onMove(SQLiteCursor.java:150)
            at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:214)
            at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToNext(AbstractCursor.java:245)
            at com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders.dbDataSource.queryToList(dbDataSource.java:147)
            at com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders.Reminder.relationshipSpace(Reminder.java:104)
            at com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders.Reminder.determineReminder(Reminder.java:83)
            at com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders.MainActivity.changeReminder(MainActivity.java:144)
            at com.mycompany.dudesmyreminders.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:97)
            at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2907)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:350)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onMenuItemSelected(ActionBarActivity.java:155)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate$1.onMenuItemSelected(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:74)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.onMenuItemSelected(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:556)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:802)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:153)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:949)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:939)
            at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:596)
            at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:145)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19858)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

EDIT: SOLVED.  Late in the evening I couldn't see that it WAS one of the methods that I added cursor.close to, which was causing the problem.  The method calls cursorToDB_Row.  It didn't like that I closed the cursor there.

```
//assumes ID is column 0 and the main string (usually name) is 1
private dbData cursorToDB_Row(Cursor cursor, String myTable) {
    dbData dbData = new dbData();
    dbData.setId(cursor.getLong(0)); //Id column
    dbData.setDbData(cursor.getString(1)); //primary string column
    dbData.setTable(myTable);
    //cursor.close();
    return dbData;
}
```

Comment: You should post the solution as an answer and mark it as accepted so that the others having the same issue may find it at the very first glance.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED. Late in the evening I couldn't see that it WAS one of the methods, which I added cursor.close to, that was causing the problem. The method calls cursorToDB_Row. It didn't like that I closed the cursor there.  I commented it out as you see below, and it worked.

```
//assumes ID is column 0 and the main string (usually name) is 1
private dbData cursorToDB_Row(Cursor cursor, String myTable) {
    dbData dbData = new dbData();
    dbData.setId(cursor.getLong(0)); //Id column
    dbData.setDbData(cursor.getString(1)); //primary string column
    dbData.setTable(myTable);
    //cursor.close();
    return dbData;
}
```